# How to convert .px files into dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have .px file and I am trying to convert it to dataframe in python.
If thats not possible can I convert it into excel/csv files and then into dataframe
I did some search, I found that we can read the data files in python by download pyaxis, but there are no examples of transforming them into pandas datafram

Answer (score 5):

You can use pyaxis to extract data from a *.px file to a pandas dataframe (see: https://pypi.org/project/pyaxis/)

```
from pyaxis import pyaxis

#set file path (or URL)
fp = r"\\folder\file.px" 
#parse contents of *.px file
px = pyaxis.parse(uri = fp , encoding = 'ISO-8859-2')

#store data as pandas dataframe
data_df = px['DATA']
#store metadata as a dictionary (not necessary in this case, but might be helpful)
meta_dict = px['METADATA']
```